# Does Delphi 's REGION directive support a default 'folded' attribute?

Tags: delphi, region

I can't seem to find the option to make Delphi collapse a {$REGION}...{$ENDREGION}-block by default (by which I mean : directly after opening a file). Is it actually possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be a good feature for a 3th-party add-in like GExpert or Castalia or something, though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it isn't.

At least, there is no reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in d2009 a folded region will remain folded the next time that you open that project.  This may be tied to the 'save project desktop' option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use D2007/2009 but at least for Delphi 2006 and below: no.